# Шаблонизаторы vs быстродействие, удобство, гибкость

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы

Надеюсь, что не подниму сейчас холивар) В общем-то всегда удивлялся фанатам шаблонизаторов и хочется послушать аргументы в их пользу. Не понимаю, какой смысл в написании псевдокода на псевдоязыке, который либо компилируется, либо (омфг) транслируется во время запроса к странице, который к тому же реально сложнее для восприятия. Скомпилированный код того же smarty, по сравнению с нативным шаблоном, захламлен чем-то явно лишним, сам код намного менее гибок, чем php, малопонятные конструкции циклов, пляски с бубном на банальном разделении контента в 3 столбика, etc etc...

Но при этом даже здесь от "старожилов" и явно не глупых людей слышу постоянно "используйте шаблонизаторы типа Смарти". Итак, вопрос: а, собственно, зачем?

ЗЫ: Я не против шаблонизаторов в принципе(только извращений типа псевдокода с "компиляцией"). То, с чем я работаю, работает по такому принипу (минимальный код):

```
function assignTemplate($file, $tmpl, $params = array()) {
  ob_start();
  if (!is_file($file)) {
    echo 'No file';
    } elseif(!is_file($tmpl)) {
    echo 'No template';
    } else {
    require $file ;
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
    require $tmpl ;
    }
  $result = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $result;
  }
```

Comment: PHP лучший шаблонизатор , ибо для этого он создавался

Comment: -1 Поработайте с Битриксом - поймете. =)

Comment: Согласен с прозвучавшими ответами (Андрюша, Зоркий, ling) - в основном и контроллеры и шаблоны "ваяю" сам, посему нет нужды в искусственных "шаблонизаторах упрощающих работу верстальщиков". Пытался пользоваться Смарти - показался мне он надуманным, громоздким, с кучей лишнего "барахла". Сейчас все циклы и управляющие конструкции в шаблонах - голый php, единственное "допущение" - замену определенных строк на их "значения" делаю в самом конце используя preg_replace()...

Comment: ling, Битрикс, да не дай бог :)

Comment: @ling @Зоркий последние 2 года работаю с джумлой. Битрикс - не такое уж и зло =(

Comment: 2Андрюша, php никогда не был шаблонизатором. Это скорее средство автоматизации наполнения контентом. Шаблонизация - несколько другое.

Comment: Дабы не захламлять ответы. Идеальным шаблонизатором я вижу xTemplate. Только в нем я увидел полное отделение кода от верстки (кстати если кто знает аналоги подскажите).

Comment: PHP с первых версий был именно что, по сути, шаблонизатором. Препроцессором, если точнее, о чем явно говорит расшифровка последней «P» в акрониме. Да и по родовой отметине — `<? ... ?>` — это прекрасно видно.

Comment: PHP это не шаблонизатор хватит бред писать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть шаблонов, - абстрагировать верстку от кода на PHP, облегчить **верстальщикам** (а не программистам) работу. По чему не стоит писать свой шаблон **координально** синтаксически отличающийся от сматри и иже с ним? Дело в том, что верстальщику легче привыкнуть к одному языку шаблонов (или использовать его подмножество), чем под каждый проект изучать свой (особенно если он на жизнь зарабатывает фрилансом).

Мощные шаблонизаторы по типу смарти, благополучно транслируют свой код в пхп и кэшируют его (поэтому замедление будет заметно только при трансляции нового шаблона в код, дальше все будет работать из кэша). Да, он не читаемый, но он и не должен быть читаем человеком, для человека есть текст шаблона, который он должен изменять.

P.S. Могу поспорить каждый писал свой шаблонизатор, еще и потому что это легче чем изучать чужой и пользоваться им (**прошу не обижаться**, я сам такой :) ).

Comment: А что мешает программисту взять у верстальщика хтмл-код и расставить циклы-переменные?) Не думаю, что это займет для какого-нибудь каталога больше часа. К слову, - то, что вы назвали "замедлением" при обновлении шаблона, у меня несколько раз отваливалось по таймауту.

Comment: Программисту мешает, то что это не его работа, зачем отнимать хлеб у верстальщика (данное заявление актуально для контор со средней численностью, где имеется четкое разделение труда). По поводу замедления, это конечно печально что у вас отваливалось, могу посоветовать делать файлы шаблона поменьше и выставить таймаут на время генерации побольше :).


Я не отвергаю написание своего шаблонизатора, я просто пытаюсь объяснить в чем был смысл создания столь мощных "монстров", например, таких как смарти :

Comment: Нууу допустим верстальщик вссе равно должен знать список переменных, структуру массивов и т.п., верстальщик вообще без навыков программирования ничего хорошего не сделает. Итого либо верстальщик разбирает код, либо программист расставляет переменные. В общем случае верстальщик решит эту задачу медленнее.

Comment: Программист и верстальщик договариваются о протоколе (имена переменных, структуры массивов/объектов). Понимаете, верстальщик тот же программист, только программист пишет, например, на php, а верстальщик языке шаблонов. И если оба хорошо знают свои языки, то договориться о взаимодействии не проблема. А из-за того что каждый из них хорошо знает свою область в результате получается качественный продукт :)

Comment: Ответ принят, тк это единственный ответ "в защиту смарти")

Comment: Я бы даже сказал, что это не только в защиту смарти, а вообще в защиту мощных, "промышленных" подсистем шаблонизации :)

Answer (score 2):

Если честно, я работаю со своим шаблонизатором, который знает только блоки (содержат что угодно и могут дублироваться) и метки (заменяются значением). Мне это удобно потому, что для исправления шаблона мне не надо копаться в php-коде, верстка шаблонов действительно похожа на верстку, а не программирование, да и верстальщику, ничего не понимающему в php, будет легче ориентироваться.

Поклонников Смарти я тоже не понимаю - код страшен как смерть, да и далеких от программирования людей к нему лучше не подпускать. Весь функционал Смарти легко укладывается в обычный php, без надобности извращаться с псевдоязыком.

Answer (score 2):

Шаблоны предназначены для:
 1. разделения логики и представления;
 2. упрощения написания и последующего чтения кода.

Шаблон — это domain-specific language. Smarty, в этом плане, это не особо интересен — разницы между «`<?php if ($foo) { ?>`» и «`{{ if $foo }}`» не очень много, хотя она есть — и не только синтаксическая. Посмотрите, например, на [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) (реализация для [PHP](https://github.com/everzet/jade.php)) — это более интересный и наглядный пример, как DSL упрощает жизнь.

Answer (score 1):

Мне очень полюбился процессор XSLT. Работает быстро, без нареканий, кое-где есть тонкости, но уж очень подкупает своей простотой. Кроме того, использование дополнительной обработки результатов именно в шаблоне тоже удобная "фича". Под-шаблоны и т.п. мелочи, которые делают все немного приятнее.

Кроме того, легко можно привинтить ко многим интерпретаторам, лично я работал с ним на PHP и VB.

Думаю, что и к фрейм-воркам легко его можно прикрутить, одной функцией в десять строк он встраивается в Codeigniter.

Не претендую на панацею, но как вариант, возможно кому-то тоже приглянется.

Answer (score 1):

Только программист пишет, например, на php, а верстальщик на языке шаблонов. Ну и зачем два   языка, если PHP сам по себе шаблонизатор?

В чем преимущество `{$msg}` над  `&lt;?=$msg?>`?  Как  ни  крути, а  некие  скриплеты  втыкать надо.

Мне очень полюбился процессор XSLT. Работает быстро, без нареканий, кое-где есть тонкости.  Тонкость одна: ему  надо скармливать XML. То есть делать разметку, которую XSLT превратит  в другую разметку.